# Экспорт таблицы в csv файл с помощью php

Tags: php

Есть скрипт php, который реализует экспорт таблицы в SCV файл.Когда открываешь,выдает непонятные символы.Скорее всего проблема в кодировке,но я целый день бьюсь головой об стену и все попытки тщетны.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам скрипт:

```
$query = "SELECT id,producer,name,short,full,nval,price_v,price1_v,price2_v,price3_v FROM `ve_goods` WHERE producer='iptronic'";
$result = mysqli_query(DB::db(), $query);

$number_of_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_fields; $i++) {
    $headers[] = mysqli_field_name($result, $i);
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; utf-8; windows-1251');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}

function mysqli_field_name($result, $field_offset)
{
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $field_offset);
    return is_object($properties) ? $properties->name : null;
}
```

Comment: это файл в кодировке `utf8` открытый как `windows-1251`. При открытии CSV в эксель нужно выбрать правильную кодировку и разделитель.

Comment: Измените заголовок `header('Content-Type: text/csv; utf-8; windows-1251');` на `header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: да изначально ,код так и был написан 
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'); это уже был мой эксперимент  header('Content-Type: text/csv; utf-8; windows-1251'); В общем не так и не так не работает

Answer (score 0):

Добавил такую строчку кода и символы начали отлично отображаться

```
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
```